# kendo ui grid and not passing paramater back on batch create

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid that I am trying to save some model data this is the grid below:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.TeachingLearningList)
.Name("TeachLearnGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Width(50).Hidden(true);
    columns.Bound(p => p.SelectedSubject).Title("Subject").ClientTemplate("#=SelectedSubject.Name#").Width(150);
    columns.Bound(p => p.StrategyItem).Title("Strategy").ClientTemplate("#=StrategyItem.Name#").Width(200);
    columns.Bound(p => p.CreatedDateTime).Format("{0:dd MMM yy HH:mm}").Title("Created Date");
    columns.Bound(p => p.ReminderDate).Format("{0:dd MMM yy HH:mm}").Title("Reminder Date Time").Width(200);
    columns.Bound(p => p.CompletedDateTime).Format("{0:dd MMM yy HH:mm}").Title("Completed Date");
    columns.Bound(p => p.Completed).Title("Completed");


})
.Pageable()
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
{
    toolbar.Create();
    toolbar.Save().HtmlAttributes(new { id = "TLSave" });
})
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.Scrollable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(p => p.ID);
                    model.Field(p => p.ID).Editable(false);
                    model.Field(p => p.SelectedSubject).DefaultValue(ViewData["defaultSubject"] as DataAccessLibrary.Classes.Subject).Editable(true);
                    model.Field(p => p.StrategyItem).DefaultValue(ViewData["defaultStrategy"] as DataAccessLibrary.Classes.ParStrategy).Editable(true);
                    model.Field(p => p.CreatedDateTime).Editable(false);
                    model.Field(p => p.CompletedDateTime).Editable(false);
                    model.Field(p => p.ReminderDate).DefaultValue(DateTime.Now);


                })
                .ServerOperation(false)

                .Batch(true)
                .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                .Read(read => read.Action("Get_TeachingLearning", "Student").Data("thisStudent"))
                .Create(create => create.Action("Create_TeachingLearning", "Student").Data("thisStudent"))
                .Update(update => update.Action("Update_TeachingLearning", "Student").Data("thisStudent"))
)

)
```

I then use this piece of javacript to attach the studentid

```
function thisStudent() {
    var studentID = $("#Students").val();

    if (studentID == 'undefined' || studentID < 1) {
        studentID = 0;
    }



    console.log("This Student Fired: " + studentID);
    return
    {
        currentID: studentID
    };
}
```

and then finally send it to this action

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Create_TeachingLearning([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,[Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<StudentToParStrategy> students , int currentID = 0  )
    {
        List<StudentToParStrategy> results = new List<StudentToParStrategy>();

        //if (studentItems != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        //{
        //    foreach (StudentToParStrategy strategy in studentItems)
        //    {

        //        results.Add(strategy);
        //    }
        //}

        return Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

Now for some reason the currentID is always returned as a zero and no matter what I try to do I don't seem to be able to get a value coming through.

If anyone can shed any light on what it is I am doing wrong that would be great as I haven't managed to find any sort of solution.

I can see the items that I have created have been passed in but Kendo must be doing something sneaky behind the scenes with regards to pushing this data across.

As you may be able to tell I am still fairly new to the MVC/Kendo world.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: See this it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330513/kendo-ui-grid-not-rebinding-after-search-button-click/18358052#18358052

Comment: Where is `Students` in your grid. i an not seen any `Students` entity in your grid.

Comment: This grid is part of the overall system and I have a combobox that has a student name with the value behind it hence the thisStudent() to get that back. It is a property of the model but I have not exposed it to the grid as when a new item is created it will not have a student id associated with it.